# Shared Memory in Python doesn't work if used within a Class

Tags: python, shared-memory, cpython

I'm using the `multiprocessing.shared_memory` module in Python to very rapidly send images between Python processes on the same computer. When I use the shared memory code raw, it works without any problem.

However, when I try to abstract it into a class, which would make it easier to use, it doesn't work and gives this error: `Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)")` (which has been seen on SO before, but for the underlying C functions, which doesn't help me a lot).

Working code:

```py
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import cv2

w, h = 1920, 1080
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, name="SharedVideoBuffer", size=w*h*3)
im = np.ndarray((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8, buffer=shm.buf)

image = cv2.imread("19201080.jpg")

while True:
    im[:] = image
```

Code that errors:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import cv2

w, h = 1920, 1080


class SharedMemImagePub:
    def __init__(self):
        shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, name="SharedVideoBuffer", size=w * h * 3)
        self.im = np.ndarray((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8, buffer=shm.buf)

    def publish_image(self, cv_image):
        self.im[:] = cv_image


if __name__ == '__main__':
    shmem_image_pub = SharedMemImagePub()
    image = cv2.imread("19201080.jpg")
    while True:
        shmem_image_pub.publish_image(image)
```

This code should be the same for anything else in Python but in this case, it does not act identically. Does anyone know why?

Comment: How is it different?

Comment: You have several hard coded values that make it so we cannot reproduce. Can you rewrite this as an ndarray that does't depend on a specific jpg or image size? Also, you need to close `shm` when done. In the second case, `shm` is deleted when init completes. That may have something to do with it. Add `shm` to the object on creation and include a close. See if that helps.

Comment: To elaborate on tdelaney's suggestion, I would suggest storing it as `self.shm` so you keep a reference to the `SharedMemory` object, which will prevent it from being automatically garbage collected when you reach the end of the scope in which it was defined.

Comment: @dskrypa Thank you, that solved it. Reminds me of memory leaks in C, probably because it is exactly that.